# get the Type for a object declared dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, types

I would like to get the Type for an dynamic object, something like:

```
dynamic tmp = Activator.CreateInstance(assembly, nmspace + "." + typeName);
Type unknown = tmp.GetType();
```

Except that in the above, GetType() returns the type of the wrapper for dynamic objects not the type of the wrapped object. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like we need more detail. I don't see anything wrong with what you have.

Comment: If I print the name for the unknown type I get: "ObjectHandle" not the type of the underlying dynamic object.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to do this...

```
Type unknown = ((ObjectHandle)tmp).Unwrap().GetType();
```

By the way, this is a little confusing because if you call Activator.CreateInstance on a type in your current assembly...

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo))
```

...the object is not wrapped and the original code works fine.

Comment: btw, it does this to prevent the assembly being loaded into the current appdomain needlessly. When you unwrap, it will be loaded.

Comment: ObjectHandle?   You do realize .NET Remoting is deprecated... and will never exist in .NET Core!

Comment: @Latency The answer is from 2011, they obviously didn't and couldn't have anticipated a framework that would have came out years later.

Comment: Oh, yeah.. you are right!  I overlooked the date on this post and assumed it was from this year.

Comment: Not working in my case. In framework 4.8 anyhow `dynamic` is NOT castable to `ObjectHandle` it gives the following error : `{"Cannot convert type 'System.__ComObject' to 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle'"}`

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Activator.CreateInstance, you can directly use:

```
object tmp = Activator.CreateInstance(assembly, nmspace + "." + typeName);
Type unknown = tmp.GetType();
```

Comment: Aren't objects slightly different then dynamics?