# How do I check type of dynamic datatype at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamic, types

In my ASP.NET website, I have a method that returns a value of type `dynamic`. This method, depending on certain criteria and results, will then either return a Boolean value or SortedList.

There is too much code to paste, but for example:

```
public dynamic ReturnThis(dynamic value)
{
    if(someConditionIsMet)
    {
        value = true;
    }
    else
    {
        value = new List<String>().Add(new Person() { Name = "Travis" });
    }

    return value;
}
```

My problem is, I would like to determine the `datatype` of value after calling this method before acting on or reading its data. But I am unsure how to check what type `dynamic value` is. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get the Type for a object declared dynamic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362532/get-the-type-for-a-object-declared-dynamic)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just read this on another SO question...hopefully it will do the trick for you:

```
Type unknown = ((ObjectHandle)value).Unwrap().GetType();
```

Read and upvote this question for more info:
[get the Type for a object declared dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362532/get-the-type-for-a-object-declared-dynamic)

Comment: not working `{"Cannot convert type 'System.__ComObject' to 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle'"}` dynamic is not castable to `ObjectHandle`

Answer (score 34):

Both solutions are working for me. In the documentation Smeegs linked to, the `is` keyword was mentioned. And I came up with a slightly more readable solution:

`if(value is Boolean) { }` and `if(value is List<Person>) { }`

---

A working test:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3348
{
    class Program
    {
        class Person
        {
            string Name = "";
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Assigning List to value");
            dynamic value = new List<Person>();

            if (value is List<Person>)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("value is a list");
            }

            value = false;

            Console.WriteLine("Assigning bool to value");
            if (value is Boolean)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("value is bool");
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

You should just be able to use `GetType()`.  Like so:

```
dynamic returnedValue = ReturnThis(value);
var returnType = returnedValue.GetType();
```

[Here is some more information on `GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: According to the other answer, `GetType()` doesn't seem to behave as you're suggesting on `dynamic` types.

Comment: It should for primitive types like `string` and `boolean`, but I'm not 100%

Comment: no, GetType on a dynamic object returns the type dynamic. not helpful.

Answer (score 7):

```
dynamic dyn = 1;
Type t = ((object)dyn).GetType();
```

Works just fine!

Comment: This does not work it return `{Name = "__ComObject" FullName = "System.__ComObject"}`

Answer (score 5):

Given a dynamic type:

```
dynamic dynVar;
Type type;
```

A merely declared, uninitialized `dynamic` variable `dynVar` will throw an exception of
Type **Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException** as you are performing **runtime binding on a null reference**, when performing Type-*Reflection* via `dynVar.GetType()`.

- As pointed out by "Troy Carlson", one may use, the rather slow method via a remoted [MarshalByRefObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject(v=vs.110).aspx):

  ```
   Type type = ((ObjectHandle)dynVar).Unwrap().GetType();
   // > type...is null
  ```
- But a simple null check as for any other type would suffice:

  ```
   type = dynVar == null ? null : dynVar.GetType();
  ```
- or...

  ```
   type = dynVar?.GetType();
  ```