# Dynamic does not contain a definition for GetType()

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, c#-7.0

I have a variable of type dynamic in my code what I am trying to do is get the type of the assigned object but it seems that there are no properties or methods available in the dynamic field.

My code is something like:

```
dynamic readings;

private void method()
{
    Type type= readings.GetType();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Reference for using GetType:

[How do I check type of dynamic datatype at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143184/how-do-i-check-type-of-dynamic-datatype-at-runtime)

Comment: What is the value of your `readings` field when you call `method()`?

Comment: Have you tried the accepted answer from the question linked in your post? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23143276/5062791

Comment: Your stated reference does not directly use `GetType()` but instead `((ObjectHandle)readings).Unwrap().GetType()`

Comment: Additionally, from Lorenzo's answer in that same post, if the value is null then `type = readings == null ? null : readings.GetType();`

Comment: Well the thing is i cannot find `ObjectHandle` in my xamarin project

Comment: It's available in Xamarin, you need to add reference to System.Runtime

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.unwrap?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I have already tried the accepted answer, ObjectHandle is not available in Xamarin.Forms .Net Standard 2.0!

Comment: Lemme try that quickly

Comment: Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies...

Comment: Most of the time you use `dynamic` you´re using it whrong. Having said this, why not just use `object` in the first place, instead of `dynamic`?

Comment: @ColinM Well `System.Runtime` does not seem to have ObjectHandle for some reason!

Comment: @DavidG Tell that to my API Developer...

Comment: @HimBromBeere I am not a big fan of dynamic either, to be honest, but what can I do here I am not the one in control...

Comment: But this is your code, so why can't you stop using dynamic?

Comment: I already did actually, Thanks for the suggestion anyway. After reading about it I realised. it does not fit my requirement anyway. `Object` it is :D

Comment: Well, I would also say using `object` is a code smell too, but since we cannot see your code, I cannot suggest anything better.

Comment: Well, the thing is that we do not have a proper response, based on the case the response can be of more than 5 types hence this...

Comment: If you know the response, then you should have 5 types.

Comment: Umm, how can I have five types of one property? Also, more types can be added in the future :/

Comment: But if you don't know what is in the object, how can you possibly use it?

Comment: "How can I have five types of one property" - Welcome to Generics, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

Comment: Again I am aware of generics but you are misunderstanding my question.  I have to deserialize this object from an API and then check what I got, using generics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just cast it to `object`:

```cs
Type type = ((object)readings).GetType();
```

Being `dynamic` means that all calls can be intercepted, but that's a compiler trick, not an inherent feature of the type. Casting it to `object` means that the compiler *stops doing that*. Behind the scenes, `dynamic` is just a fancy word for `object` *anyway*.

Note, however, that it is usually a bad idea to mix reflection (`GetType()`) and `dynamic`; while objects *can work as `dynamic`* (by re-exposing the reflection API as `dynamic`), this is not always the case, and many (most?) implementations of `dynamic` are presenting entirely artificial members that *do not exist* in terms of reflection. That's *kinda the main point* of `dynamic`, with "oh, it also lets you be lazy and talk to types without knowing their type" just a handy side-effect.

Comment: Too little changes for an approved edit, `GetType` ;-)

Comment: @ColinM fixed, ta