# C# How to use GetType in a dynamic object?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a `dynamic` an I need to find its type to use the type name. The only thing I
'm sure in this point of the code is that the dynamic object is from a custom class.

I want to avoid to make multiple checks with `if`.
I tried `GetType` and `typeof`, but no success.

Comment: Please read [ask].  Share some code (ideally  a [mre]) and description what you want and what exactly is not working.

Comment: "but no success" doesn't tell us *anything* about what happened when you tried to use `GetType`.

Comment: Do you know the possible classes? Do they have anything in common? Often using `dynamic` is the root of your evil, not the solution. Anyway `GetType` should actually give you the runtime-type, so please elaborate on what "no success" means. Do you get any error? Unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only thing I 'm sure in this point of the code is that the dynamic object is from a custom class.

Assuming you mean a simple POCO that is *exposed via `dynamic`*, then forget about the `dynamic` completely:

```cs
var obj = (object)yourDynamicThing;
var type = obj.GetType();
// from here: reflection and/or type tests all the way down
```

---

In the more general case (where you don't know anything about the instance): reflection (`GetType()`) and `dynamic` are two *completely different models*; the type of the `dynamic` is irrelevant and will often be a private implementation type (`DapperRow`, for example) or the simple `ExpandoObject`. Asking what the type is: is not a reasonable question.

Knowing the type *won't help you much* if the type is a `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, i.e. implements `dynamic` in a bespoke way.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the solution from this Thread works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7362847/11879204

```
Type unknown = ((ObjectHandle)tmp).Unwrap().GetType();
```

Comment: Don't link to questions/answers on this site. Mark the question as a duplicate and move on.